# Multisplitting in AWK

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I would like to execute 2 splits using AWK (i have 2 fields separator), the String of data i'm working on would look like something like so:

```
data;digit&int&string&int&digit;data;digit&int&string&int&digit
```

As you can see the outer field separator is a semicolon, and the nested one is an ampersand.
What i'm doing with awk is (suppose that the String would be in a variable named test)

```
echo ${test} | awk '{FS=";"} {print $2}' | awk '{FS="&"} {print $3}'
```

This should catch the "String" word, but for some reason this is not working.
It seems like the second pipe its not being applied, as i see only the result of the first awk function
Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try that :

```
echo "$test" | awk -F'[;&]' '{print $4}'
```

I specify a multiple separator in `-F'[;&]'`

Answer (score 5):

use awk arrays

```
echo $test | awk -F';' '{split($2, arr, "&"); print(arr[3])}'
```

Answer (score 4):

The other answers give working solutions, but they don't really explain the problem.

The problem is that setting `FS` inside a regular `{ ... }` block the `awk` script won't cause `$1`, `$2`, etc. to be re-calculated for the current line; so `FS` will be set for any later lines, but the very first line will already have been split by whitespace. To set `FS` before running the script, you can use a `BEGIN` block (which is run before the first line); or, you can use the `-F` command-line option.

Making either of those changes will fix your command:

```
echo "$test" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"} {print $2}' | awk 'BEGIN{FS="&"} {print $3}'
echo "$test" | awk -F';' '{print $2}' | awk -F'&' '{print $3}'
```

(I also took the liberty of wrapping `$test` in double-quotes, since unquoted parameter-expansions are a recipe for trouble. With your value of `$test` it would have been fine, but I make it a habit to *always* use double-quotes, just in case.)

Comment: This problem does not call for spawning the interpreter twice. A `BEGIN` block can also be used instead of `-F`.

Comment: @jordanm: Re: "This problem does not call for spawning the interpreter twice": Yes. My answer was quite explicit in stating that the other answers (which did not call `awk` twice) gave working solutions, and that my sole goal was to explain what was going wrong with the OP's command. I therefore aimed to give a *minimal* change to the OP's command that would address the problem, because that is the clearest way to explain the problem. (Do you disagree?) Re: "A `BEGIN` block can also be used instead of `-F`": Good point. I'll edit my answer to mention that.